# Excel VBA to summarize last cell of certain column to 'summary' worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to summarize worksheets (invoices) into "Summary-Sheet" using below code that I found Internet. I am unsuccessfully trying to modify it to select last cell in column F (total amount) which represents total of each invoice.

Total in column F has varying row number based on items sold.

**Please help me in updating code to it select total amount from last cell having value in column F.**

Thank you!

```
Sub Summary_All_Worksheets_With_Formulas()
Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim Newsh As Worksheet
Dim myCell As Range
Dim ColNum As Integer
Dim RwNum As Long
Dim Basebook As Workbook

With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

'Delete the sheet "Summary-Sheet" if it exist
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary-Sheet").Delete
On Error GoTo 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Add a worksheet with the name "Summary-Sheet"
Set Basebook = ThisWorkbook
Set Newsh = Basebook.Worksheets.Add
Newsh.Name = "Summary-Sheet"

'The links to the first sheet will start in row 2
RwNum = 1

For Each Sh In Basebook.Worksheets
    If Sh.Name <> Newsh.Name And Sh.Visible Then
        ColNum = 1
        RwNum = RwNum + 1
        'Copy the sheet name in the A column
        Newsh.Cells(RwNum, 1).Value = Sh.Name

        For Each myCell In Sh.Range("A1,A2,C3,E3,C4,E4,C5,E5")  '<--Change the range
            ColNum = ColNum + 1
            Newsh.Cells(RwNum, ColNum).Formula = _
            "='" & Sh.Name & "'!" & myCell.Address(False, False)
        Next myCell

    End If
Next Sh

Newsh.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit

With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: last cell in column F can be accessed like this: `Sh.Range("F" & Sh.Range("F1000000").end(xlUp).Row)`

Comment: Thanks, it works but is there a way to merge your argument with **Sh.Range("A1,....E5")** where I wrote a 'comment change range here'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to loop through the cells to find your "total amount".  I modified part of your code as follows:

```
    If Sh.Name <> Newsh.Name And Sh.Visible Then
      ColNum = 1
      RwNum = RwNum + 1
      'Copy the sheet name in the A column
      Newsh.Cells(RwNum, 1).Value = Sh.Name

      'put this declaration on top
      Dim CellsArray() As String
      Dim RangeString As String
      Dim intCount As Integer

      'your collection of ranges
      RangeString = "A1,A2,C3,E3,C4,E4,C5,E5"

      'split them into array
      CellsArray = Split(RangeString, ",")

      'loop through your array
      For intCount = LBound(CellsArray) To UBound(CellsArray)

        ColNum = ColNum + 1
        Newsh.Cells(RwNum, ColNum).Formula = _
        "='" & Sh.Name & "'!" & CellsArray(intCount) '<- access each range in array

      Next intCount


      'Find last row in the column: "Total Amount"
      LastRow = Sh.Cells(Sh.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

      'Assign that cell to myCell
      Set myCell = Sh.Range("F" & LastRow)

      'total
      ColNum = ColNum + 1
      Newsh.Cells(RwNum, ColNum).Formula = _
      "='" & Sh.Name & "'!" & myCell.Address(False, False)

    End If
```

Edit: I added the loop cycle in the middle as requested

Comment: Thank you. One last thing, if you see my post above that cycles through eight cells (i.e. **Sh.Range("A1,A2,C3,E3,C4,E4,C5,E5")**). How can I fit/patch your code to mine? Basically, I want mentioned 8 cells and total amount using your code in 'summary sheet'.